# Set RadioButton Checked in custom adapter

Tags: android

I have radio button in list-view which is working fine with my custom adapter.
The problem is I want to set radio button checked if answer already exists in my model.
Following is adapter class:

```
public class options_data_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChildListDataModel> {
private Activity context;
private List<ChildListDataModel> data;
private int resId;
MySharedPreferences mpref;
private RadioButton mSelectedRB;
private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
boolean[] itemChecked;


public options_data_adapter(Context context, int resource, List<ChildListDataModel> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = (Activity) context;
    this.resId = resource;
    this.data = objects;
    mpref = new MySharedPreferences(context);
    itemChecked = new boolean[objects.size()];

}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {


    final Holder h;// = null;
    if (v == null) {
        h = new Holder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(resId, parent, false);

        h.check = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.c1);
        h.radio=(RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.r1);
        h.spinner=(Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.s1);
        h.btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_spiner);
        v.setTag(h);
    } else {
        h = (Holder) v.getTag();
    }

    Log.d("soh_answer", data.get(position).answere);

    if(mpref.GetquestionType().equals("Radio")){
        h.check.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        h.radio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        h.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        h.btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        h.radio.setText(data.get(position).answere);
        if(data.get(position).checked.equals("1")){
            h.radio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
            h.radio.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            h.radio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_ackgroun1);
            h.radio.setChecked(false);
        }
        h.radio.setTag(position);
        h.radio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Log.i("ID of radiobutton","Order Edit @ position : " + pos);
                if (position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null) {
                    mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                    ((VasNBIActivity) context).removeChecked(data.get(mSelectedPosition).id);
                    mSelectedRB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_ackgroun1);
                    /*data.get(mSelectedPosition).checked="0";*/
                }
                mSelectedPosition = position;
                ((VasNBIActivity) context).addChecked(data.get(mSelectedPosition).id);
                h.radio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
               /* data.get(mSelectedPosition).checked="1";*/
                mSelectedRB = (RadioButton) v;
            }

        });
        if (mSelectedPosition != position) {
            h.radio.setChecked(false);
        }else {
            h.radio.setChecked(true);
            if(mSelectedRB != null && h.radio != mSelectedRB){
                mSelectedRB = h.radio;
            }
        }





    }else if(mpref.GetquestionType().equals("Checkbox")){
        h.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        h.radio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        h.check.setText(data.get(position).answere);
        h.btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //=============================================================================


        if(data.get(position).checked.equals("1")) {
            itemChecked[position] = true;
        }else{
            itemChecked[position] = false;

        }





        if (itemChecked[position]) {
            h.check.setChecked(true);
            ((VasNBIActivity) context).addChecked(data.get(position).id);
           // h.check.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
        }else {
            h.check.setChecked(false);
        }
        h.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (h.check.isChecked()&& data.get(position).checked.equals("0")) {
                       itemChecked[position] = true;
                        ((VasNBIActivity) context).addChecked(data.get(position).id);
                       // h.check.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
                        data.get(position).checked = "1";

                }
                else {
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
                    ((VasNBIActivity) context).removeChecked(data.get(position).id);
                   // h.check.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_ackgroun1);
                    data.get(position).checked="0";
                }
            }
        });

        //for spinner type questions

    }else {
        h.check.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        h.radio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        h.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        h.btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        h.btn.setText(data.get(position).answere);
        h.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                data.get(position).spinner_value = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }


    return v;
}
private class Holder {

    CheckBox check;
    RadioButton radio;
    Spinner spinner;
    Button btn;

    }
}
```

And here is the code for radio button:

```
 if(mpref.GetquestionType().equals("Radio")){
        h.check.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        h.radio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        h.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        h.btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        h.radio.setText(data.get(position).answere);
        if(data.get(position).checked.equals("1")){
            h.radio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
            h.radio.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            h.radio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_ackgroun1);
            h.radio.setChecked(false);
        }
        h.radio.setTag(position);
        h.radio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Log.i("ID of radiobutton","Order Edit @ position : " + pos);
                if (position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null) {
                    mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                    ((VasNBIActivity) context).removeChecked(data.get(mSelectedPosition).id);
                    mSelectedRB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_ackgroun1);
                    /*data.get(mSelectedPosition).checked="0";*/
                }
                mSelectedPosition = position;
                ((VasNBIActivity) context).addChecked(data.get(mSelectedPosition).id);
                h.radio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
               /* data.get(mSelectedPosition).checked="1";*/
                mSelectedRB = (RadioButton) v;
            }

        });
        if (mSelectedPosition != position) {
            h.radio.setChecked(false);
        }else {
            h.radio.setChecked(true);
            if(mSelectedRB != null && h.radio != mSelectedRB){
                mSelectedRB = h.radio;
            }
        }
```

I am trying to check button if its checked value=1 in list model.

addChecked and remove checked functions:

```
   public void addChecked(String val) {
    checkedValue.add(val);
}
public void removeChecked(String val) {
    checkedValue.remove(val);
}
```

How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

You check button if its checked value=1 in this code.

```
// #1
if(data.get(position).checked.equals("1")){
    h.radio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
    h.radio.setChecked(true);
}else{
    h.radio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_ackgroun1);
    h.radio.setChecked(false);
}
```

But, you change the state again this code

```
// #2
if (mSelectedPosition != position) {
    h.radio.setChecked(false);
}else {
    h.radio.setChecked(true);
    if(mSelectedRB != null && h.radio != mSelectedRB){
        mSelectedRB = h.radio;
    }
}
```

So, remove your code(#2) and try again